# Does higher Electronic use relate to lower memory

Tags: memory, devices

lots of us use electronics as memory devices--making notes, reminders, etc.

Does more use of electronics relate to lower retention? In other words, does not using your memory make it worse?

Comment: Hi elder4222, this is an interesting question but it has been asked before! (see [this question](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/532/55)). I have flagged to close as duplicate.